# Regex Greediness

Tags: python, regex

it might be hard question related regular expression but I couldn't solve it. Here is my regular expression:

```
regex = (^|(?<= ))Football( ((\S+ )+?(?=Football)|(\S+ )+)| )fun( ((\S+ )+?(?=Football)|(\S+ )+)| )Football\ is\ important((?= )|$)
```

With that I'd like to catch these:

```
text1 = "Football is fun I like Football is important"
text2 = "Fun to watch Football I think Football is important"
text3 = "Fun to watch Football I like Football"
```

but not this:

```
text4 = "Football is fun I like Football Football is important"
```

As far as I understand, expression shouldn't have matched because there is one more Football in there. Second `( ((\S+ )+?(?=Football)|(\S+ )+)| )` part should have matched `I like` because after this `Football` in there and it's not greedy because I added `?` after second `+`. The last part should have matched `Football is important` so there is one `Football` (in the middle) hanging around. How can I modify it so that it makes what I need?

**More clarification about the question:**

`( ((\S+ )+?(?=Football)|(\S+ )+)| )`part should match with not whitespace chars until it sees Football and returns what it got. So this regex shouldn't have matched with text4 because there are only two Football in it. On the otherhand `text4` contains 3 Football. Hope it's more clear now.

Sorry for the silly example; I changed my real text.

Comment: I think you may use a simple a simple regex for this job.

Comment: what's the original text you're trying to capture from?

Comment: `^Football( \w+){4} Football (\w+ )\w+$` and a lot of regexes will matches your sentence!

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not being specific. I know there are lots of matching answer for the text I gave as an example. But it's not the only text I'd like to match. Football can be in everywhere and there are more than 4 words between two Football. Let me clarify more in question.

Comment: I clarified the question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The word `fun` is mandatory after first occurence of `football` - the second and third sentences can't match since there's no `fun` there ;)

`text4` is a bit more complicated to explain. It matches, due to the second occurence of `( ((\S+ )+?(?=Football)|(\S+ )+)| )` matches `I like Football`.
Every word is matched with the inner part `(\S+ )+?`.
You're right. You're using `+?` here - but there are two opportunities for the inner part:

- match `I like (Football)`
- match `I like Football (Football)`

both are valid for `(\S+ )+?(?=Football)` - what exactly is the least part of it, only depends on what's next.

## Example

Use the pattern `(\S+ )+?(?=Football)Football` with the text `I like Football Football`. It will matche `I like Football` (as you expected).

Now, modify the pattern to `(\S+ )+?(?=Football)Football$`. You'll see that now, the complete text is matched. `$` could not match if you stop at the first occurence of `Football`. The rest of the text have to match too - and since `Football` could be matched by `\S+`, everything is perfectly valid..

Hope that helps a bit.